# Azure Dev Op: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment, 7zip

I am trying to run a Release Job on Azure Dev ops.

I have 4 tasks:

[image]

I am using Archive Remote Folder to create a 7zip backup of the deployment folder. This one in comparison to the Archive Files task let's you exclude filetypes.

My issue comes during archive, this is the error message:

[image]

I have tried adding 7zip to the environment variables, but still the same. I was thinking maybe just run a local powershell task to do the archive where I can add the quotes to the location in Program Files where 7zip is located.

Funny enough, I have the same setup for two boxes, but this runs fine on the first one.

What should I check?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PatrickLu-MSFT

Yep, that's what I figured. I have no idea how the path to the 7z exe was not treated as string. What I did in the end was to create my own powershell wrapper function around 7z and archive it that way. It all went smoothly from there.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the official [Archive Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops), Archive Remote Folder Task which is a 3rd-party extension released by community  contributor.

Have also installed and tested this task, but could not reproduce same error in our environment.

According to the [tutorial](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ggarbuglia.archiveremotefolder-task) of this task in marketplace, you need to follow below requirements:

- **Your remote server must have WinRM enabled and configured.**
- Your remote server must have 7z installed.

`'C:\Program' is not a recognized as a internal or external command` This looks like your local path `C:\Program Files\xx` include whitespace be treated as part of command line.

Since the latest update of  Archive Remote Folder Task is 11/17/2016, I don't think it's a good idea to file a bug to the author.

As you have pointed out in the question, you could just run a local powershell task to do the archive. Another choice is writing your own extension task to handle the process, you could take a look at the both open source codes of [Archive Remote Folder Task](https://github.com/ggarbuglia/TfsExtensions/tree/master/ArchiveRemoteFolder)  and [Archive Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops).